# open different div content into same container jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, containers

A little new to JQuery, I'm trying to have multiple links that open different related content into the same container.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/unbornink/3stTJ/)

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you want with this example?

Comment: when you click link 1, content 1 loads in the container, click link 2 and the content is replaced with content 2, and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `data-*` synatx of HTML5 to do it:

**HTML:**

```
<a class="link" data-link="first" href="#">link 1</a>
<a class="link" data-link="second" href="#">link 2</a>
<a class="link" data-link="third" href="#">link 3</a>

<div class="linkdetails" data-link="first" >content 1</div>
<div class="linkdetails" data-link="second" >content 2</div>
<div class="linkdetails" data-link="third" >content 3</div>
​
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('.link').toggle(function() {
    $('.linkdetails[data-link=' + $(this).data('link') + ']').animate({
        width: '200px'
    }, 300);


}, function() {
    $('.linkdetails[data-link=' + $(this).data('link') +']').animate({
        width: '0px'
    }, 300);

});​
```

[**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mpggu/)

Comment: This is almost what I was after, just need to replace the related content, rather than opening a new container

Comment: Managed to use this and solved the issue here [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/unbornink/LUKGt/)